# ORDER BY RAND() em 2 colunas

Tags: sql, mysqli

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom mais cedo postei um problema sobre a eliminacao de 1 select que foi resolvido porem agora me apareceu outro problema .

Minha ideia é criar uma playlist que priorize o status 1.
Sempre que um usuario posta o video ele é inserido com status 1.
Apos o video ser reproduzido faço um update nele mudando para status 0.
A playlist vai continuar reproduzindo os videos que possuem status 0

O problema é que quando todos os videos estiverem com status=0 a playlist sempre estara pegando o mesmo video no caso do select abaixo sempre vai pegar o id 7, estou tentando randomizar sem sucesso.

```
SELECT * FROM playlist ORDER BY status DESC,id ASC, RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM playlist ORDER BY status DESC,RAND() LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

Ao usar `id ASC, RAND()` significa que ele vai ordenar primeiro pelo `id` e caso tenha duas linhas com o mesmo valor ele irá usar o `RAND()` para ordenar. Só que isso nunca vai acontecer porque nunca vai existir duas chaves primárias (`id`) iguais na mesma tabela. Para corrigir isso retire o `id ASC` do commando

Além disso o uso da chave primária de forma ascendente como segunda opção de ordenação é descenessária, os dados da tabela já estão naturalmente ordenados pelo `id`, ao fazer qualquer consulta, com ou sem `ORDER BY`, a linha do `id` 1 nunca ficará na frente da linha do `id` 0, a não ser por efeito da ordenação de outro campo (se existir)